# Java parent's private attribute inside child constructor

Tags: java, parent-child, downcast

The title says it all, I got a class in which the variables of the constructor must be private.

```
public class AdMedia {
private String name;
private int price;

public AdMedia(){}


public AdMedia(String name, int price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
```

that comes with public `getter` `setter` of the variables of course.

Now the problem comes right after I try to make a child class named Magazine. The class should inherit the name and price but the **price is constant for every object initiation.** so they won't be on the constructor as the name.

```
public class Magazine extends AdMedia {
private int area;
private String position;
private String topics;

public Magazine() {}
public Magazine(String name, int size, String position, String topic){

    super();
    this.size = size;
    this.position = position;
    this.topic = topic;

}
```

that also comes with its own `getter` `setter` too.

I try to put the price inside the constructor but the constructor demand a passed parameter. Using `super(name)` also notifies that none of parent constructor have such shape.

This complicates me when I'm trying to `get` the `name` using parent class method `getName()` which might require some downcasting I guess?

I had try to search for the solution but most require me to change the variable's accessibility into `protected` . Would there be no other way to do it in `private` ?

EDIT : 
I forgot to mention that the result by doing what I wrote above is the unability to access Magazine name, so when I try to downcast-get the name, what returned is a null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)

Comment: what is the constant value of price ? Is it set by user who instantiates new Magazine() ? @DeanDebrio

Comment: @QuickSilver It supposed to be counted by the print amount, a variable in main, times £100 or something

Comment: @WoAiNii I understand that private means the only one can access the variables is just the class, the parent, itself and cannot be inherited except by using parent's getter-setter. I'm actually confused at  the part which I need to use the privates to a constructor that doesn't accept parameters of it (the 'price' variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your child constructor either as

```
public Magazine(String name, int size, String position, String topic){
    super();
    setName(name);
    setPrice(100); // 100 is your constant price
    this.size = size;
    this.position = position;
    this.topic = topic;
}
```

or as

```
public Magazine(String name, int size, String position, String topic){
    super(name, 100); // 100 is your constant price
    this.size = size;
    this.position = position;
    this.topic = topic;
}
```

Both ways would however open the possibility to change the price later:

```
Magazine m = new Magazine("name", 50, "position", "topic");
m.setPrice(10);
```

If you need to prevent this, you should also override the `setPrice()` setter:

```
public class Magazine extends AdMedia {

    ...
    @Override
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        // what to do here?
        // * you could either silently ignore 
        //   (which might surprise some users expecting to be able to change the price)
        // * throw an UnsupportedOperationException 
        //   (which might surprise other users which are not prepared to handle such an exception)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, the whole code fixed. I never used super like that before. Thanks!